# HTML accordion padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a little problem with my accordion.

Here you can see the code: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phmalo/shaLyapw/)

At first everything is fine, but after I open and then close one of the panels again, the padding still is there, although it should disappear.

I added the padding with javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
         panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      }  else {
         panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
         panel.style.padding = "18px";
      } 
   }
}
```

How could this be solved? Thanks for helping!

Comment: you mean the "panel.style.padding ="18px"" part?

Comment: Why should it magically disappear again? _You_ explicitly set it in your code, so who would you guess should also be the one undoing that again if it is supposed to “disappear” …? But you should rather not do that dynamically when opening the accordion items - why isn’t the padding simply in the style sheet to begin with?

Comment: I tried to add the padding in the style sheet, problem with that was, that it would still appear even though the tab is closed but only, if I run it on my website not if I run it as an seperate html file. I built the website with sp page builder and used the raw html feature to insert the accordion. So maybe its because of sp pagte builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Jquery , so why not simplifying your code as below :
you've just to got the accordion div's , and on click you toggles its active class , then [toggleSlide](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) the accordion next panel:

```js
$(".accordion").on("click",function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("active");
 var $panel = $(this).next(".panel");
  $panel.slideToggle();
  
})
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #63A539;
 border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

button.accordion.active, {
    background-color: #63A539; 
}

button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #457327; 
 
}
div.panel {
  display:none;
 border: none;
 border-color: #63A539;
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
   overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Workflow</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>Der elektronische Mitarbeiter, der Sie aktiv unterstützt.</p>
 <p>Diese Entwicklung ist eine absolute Neuheit für Versicherungsmakler. Er ermöglicht erstmals eine aktive Unterstützung bei Ihren Aufgaben:</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Vollautomatische Polizzenurgenz</li>
 <li>Vollautomatische Schadenurgenz</li>
 <li>Anforderung von Unterlagen (Kunde, VU,...)</li>
 <li>Termine setzen, Dokumente schreiben</li>
 <li>E-Mail/Fax automatisch versenden</li>
 <li>Abläufe (Vorgänge) selbst bestimmen</li>
 <li>Führungsinstrument</li>
 <li>Unterstützung im Qualitätsmanagement</li>
 <li>Bessere Ressourcen-Ausnutzung</li>
 <li>Erhöhung der Liquidität durch Optimierung</li>
 <li>Kostensenkung (Personal, Ressourcen, Arbeitszeit)</li>
 <li>Innovationsvorsprung</li>
 <li>Maklerhaftung</li>
 </ul>
 <div>
 <img class="" src="/images/2017/10/17/4_0_0_p_images_stories_fotos_wflow.jpg" alt="Workflow" width="490" height="386">
 </div>
 <p>Können Sie sich vorstellen, dass in Zukunft Ihr neuer Mitarbeiter "Workflow" all Ihre Schadenabwicklungen, Anforderungen, Polizzierungsabläufe bezüglich Urgenzen und Terminkontrolle für Sie übernimmt?</p>
 <p>Mit diesem Modul können Sie nun endlich "lästige" Aufgaben an den Computer delegieren. Dadurch wird Ihr Alltag beherrschbarer und Sie haben deutlich mehr Zeit für das Wesentliche. Sie sparen eine Menge Zeit, erhöhen damit deutlich Ihre Produktivität und vermeiden mögliche Fehlerquellen. Allein dieses Werkzeug wird Ihnen eine schnelle Amortisation der Anschaffungskosten Ihrer Software innerhalb kürzester Zeit ermöglichen. Lassen Sie sich auch in diesem Punkt bei einer persönlichen Präsentation überraschen und sehen Sie sich die vielen Einsatzmöglichkeiten dieses Moduls in der Praxis an.</p>
</div>
 
  </div>

<button class="accordion">Workflowvorlagen</button>
<div class="panel">
 <p>Dieses Modul ist eine Erweiterung zum Workflow mit vordefinierten Workflows:</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Management-Auswertung monatlich</li>
 <li>Management-Auswertung wöchentlich</li>
 <li>Heute Geburtstag/Kunde</li>
 <li>Heute Geburtstag/Vermittler</li>
 <li>Heute Geburtstag Email/Dokument</li>
 <li>Geburtstag mit Jubiläum</li>
 <li>Überwachung Kundengespräch</li>
 <li>Service Premiumkunde</li>
 <li>Überwachung Kündigungsrecht § 8 Abs.3 Vers VG</li>
 <li>Überwachung Kündigungsrecht nach Kündigungsklausel</li>
 <li>Überwachung versicherte Person</li>
 <li>Überwachung Vertragsablauf</li>
 <li>Automatische Verlängerung KFZ-Vertrag</li>
 <li>Überprüfung Vertragsstorno</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I`m new to html and just followed a guide to make the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      panel.style.padding = "0";
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      panel.style.padding = "18px";
    } 
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mgp2qju/)

Comment: But this could be solved by adding padding, but the solution from bRIMOs is the best one

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect and u have to edit a single line and u obtained your desired output.I have also change code on Jsfiddle please follow link

```
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  panel.style.padding = "0px";
  } else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  panel.style.padding = "18px";
} 
}
}
```

[jsfidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krdheeraj/8raemqLk/) 
thanks